# javascript least common subsequence, implementing the cache

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to implement the javascript version of the '[Longest Common Subsequence](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-subsequence/submissions/)' problem. I am following the java implementation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASoaQq66foQ):

```
// working solution
class BottomUp {
  public int longestCommonsubsequenceLength(String s1, String s2) {
    int cache[][] = new int[s2.length() + 1][s1.length() + 1];

    for (int s2Row = 0; s2Row <= s2.length(); s2Row++) {
      for (int s1Col = 0; s1Col <= s1.length(); s1Col++) {
        if (s2Row == 0 || s1Col == 0) {
          cache[s2Row][s1Col] = 0;
        } else if (s2.charAt(s2Row - 1) == s1.charAt(s1Col - 1)) {
          cache[s2Row][s1Col] = cache[s2Row - 1][s1Col - 1] + 1;
        }
        else {
          cache[s2Row][s1Col] = Math.max(cache[s2Row - 1][s1Col], cache[s2Row][s1Col - 1]);
        }
      }
    }
    return cache[s2.length()][s1.length()];
  }
}
```

However, when I try to initialize the and access the multi-dimensional array:

`int cache[][] = new int[s2.length() + 1][s1.length() + 1];` and access it, it tells me that is undefined.

Here is my attempt:

```
var longestCommonSubsequence = function(s1, s2) {
    let cache = [];
    let max = 0;
    
    // ***initialize cache***
    for(let i = 0; i <= s1.length; i++) {
        cache.push(new Array(s2.length + 1).fill(0));
    }

    for (let s2Row = 0; s2Row <= s2.length; s2Row++) {
      for (let s1Col = 0; s1Col <= s1.length; s1Col++) {
        if (s2Row == 0 || s1Col == 0) {
          cache[s2Row][s1Col] = 0; // crashes here. 'Cannot set property '0' of undefined

        } else if (s2.charAt(s2Row - 1) == s1.charAt(s1Col - 1)) {
          cache[s2Row][s1Col] = cache[s2Row - 1][s1Col - 1] + 1;
        }
        else {
          cache[s2Row][s1Col] = Math.max(cache[s2Row - 1][s1Col], cache[s2Row][s1Col - 1]);
        }
      }
    }

    return cache[s2.length][s1.length];
};
```

How can I implement the array in the way that is done in the Java solution?

**edit**:

It seems to work with some inputs, e.g. String 1: "abcde" String 2: "ace"

But fails with others, e.g.String 1: "pmjghexybyrgzczy" String 2: "hafcdqbgncrcbihkd"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please include the values you're passing to `longestCommonSubsequence`. It's working for me.

Comment: str1: "pmjghexybyrgzczy"
str2: "hafcdqbgncrcbihkd"

Comment: updated the question @Mordred , thanks

Comment: @Mordred I figured it out. In my first loop I'm doing     `for(let i = 0; i <= s1.length; i++) {`. If you add + 1 to .length, it will pass. I'm not sure why I need to add this though. Feel free to post an answer so I can accept, if you happen to have any insight

Comment: it will still break on other inputs. Writing up a solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the sizes used for your array initialization are reversed. I don't know if the Java version actually works correctly, but your Javascript works correctly if `s1` and `s2` are the same length, or if `s2` is longer. If `s1` is longer than `s2` it crashes because it's trying to index outside the bounds you created.

The solution was to change your initialization so that the row array is based off the length of `s2` and the columns are off the length of `s1`. Yours was going out of bounds and referencing `cache[5][0]` when your cache was of size [4][5] (for example).

Working code:

```js
var longestCommonSubsequence = function(s1, s2) {
    let cache = [];
    let max = 0;

    // ***initialize cache***
    for(let i = 0; i <= s2.length; i++) {
        cache.push(new Array(s1.length + 1).fill(0));
    }

    for (let s2Row = 0; s2Row <= s2.length; s2Row++) {
      for (let s1Col = 0; s1Col <= s1.length; s1Col++) {
        if (s2Row == 0 || s1Col == 0) {
          cache[s2Row][s1Col] = 0; 

        } else if (s2.charAt(s2Row - 1) == s1.charAt(s1Col - 1)) {
          cache[s2Row][s1Col] = cache[s2Row - 1][s1Col - 1] + 1;
        }
        else {
          cache[s2Row][s1Col] = Math.max(cache[s2Row - 1][s1Col], cache[s2Row][s1Col - 1]);
        }
      }
    }

    return cache[s2.length][s1.length];
};

console.log(longestCommonSubsequence('abc', 'bcasdf'));
console.log(longestCommonSubsequence('adcfghj', 'abcd'));
console.log(longestCommonSubsequence('abcd', 'bced'));
console.log(longestCommonSubsequence('pmjghexybyrgzczy', 'hafcdqbgncrcbihkd'));
```